# how to fix mezzanine unit test failure?

Tags: unit-testing, mezzanine

When I run my unit test I get this error:

```
FAIL: test_syntax (mezzanine.core.tests.Tests)
```

---

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/Users/taylor/aco/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/tests.py", line 459, in test_syntax
>
> self.fail("Syntax warnings!\n\n%s" % "\n".join(warnings))
>   AssertionError: Syntax warnings!
>
> mezzanine/core/models.py:340: list comprehension redefines 'name' from line 331

This is the only error I get when I run my unit tests and I have searched everywhere to figure out how to fix this error but I have found nothing useful.
Can someone please explain to me what is going on here and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are running Mezzanine 1.3.0, the current stable release. The current master branch in github does not have this issue. I just installed performed the following:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine.git#egg=Mezzanine
$ mezzanine-project project
$ python project/manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.................................................................................
.................................................................................
.................................................................................
...............................s......s..................................s.......
................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 388 tests in 30.556s

OK (skipped=3)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

For what it is worth, the `test_syntax` method that is failing in 1.3.0 runs tests with the pyflakes.Checker and pep8 Python modules. The file `mezzanine/core/models.py` had (has?) syntax errors. A brief scan of the [commits](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/commits/master/mezzanine/core/tests.py) indicates that `test_syntax` has not changed. The specific syntax that was giving the error is in `mezzanine.core.models.Orderable`'s [with_respect_to](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/core/models.py#L321-L340) method, which doesn't have any PEP8 nor pyflakes errors. When I run pyflakes against the 1.3.0 version of `mezzanine.core.models`:

```
$ pyflakes ../lib/python2.6/site-packages/mezzanine/core/models.py
../lib/python2.6/site-packages/mezzanine/core/models.py:340: list comprehension
redefines 'name' from line 331
```